# For all integers $n ≥ 2, n^3 > 2n + 1$

Tags: induction

I am having some serious trouble figuring out this induction problem. I've tried following other problems and can not seem to get the end result or understand it sufficiently.

**My attempt:**

Theorem: For all integers $n≥2, n^3 > 2n + 1$

*Proof:* We will prove this by induction. Let $P(n)$ be the statement: $n^3 > 2n + 1$. We will show $P(2)$ is true. When we let $n = 2, 2^3 = 8$ and $2(2) + 1 = 5$, so we know $P(2)$ to be true for $n^3 > 2n + 1$.

Induction Step: Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some integer $k≥2$, then $k^3>2(k)+1$. We wish to show that $P(k+1)$ is true, that is $(k+1)^3>2(k+1)+1$. We then factor it out to be $k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 >  2k + 3$. I am stuck from here. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: $k^{3}+3k^{2}+3k+1>k^{3}+3k+1>(2k+1)+3k+1>2k+1+1+1=2k+3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You will definitely want to bookmark [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future use on typesetting math. It will make your question(s) easier to read and more likely to receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main part of the inductive step:
\begin{align}
(k+1)^3 &= k^3+3k^2+3k+1\tag{expand}\\[1em]
&> (2k+1)+3k^2+3k+1\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[1em]
&> 2k+2+1\tag{since $k\geq2$}\\[1em]
&= 2(k+1)+1\tag{rearrange}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain how you determined (2k+1)+3k^2+3k+1 > 2k + 2 + 1. I see you said since k ≥ 2, but I don't quite understand how that gives you 2k+2+1

Comment: To see that $(2k+1)+3k^2+3k+1>2k+2+1$, simply note the following: $2k+1>2k; 3k^2>2; 3k>1; 1>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *conceptual* way of viewing the proof that makes it obvious, and works very generally. First construct the obvious inductive proof of the following Lemma

$\rm\:f(n) > 0\:$ for $\rm\:n\ge 2\ $ if $\rm\ f(2)> 0\:$ and $\rm\,f\,$ is increasing, i.e. $\rm\: f(n\!+\!1) \ge f(n)\:$ for $\rm\:n\ge2.\:$

So to show $\rm\:f(n) = n^3\!-2n-1> 0\:$ it suffices to show $\rm\: f(n\!+\!1)-f(n) = 3n^2\!+3n-1 \ge 0\:$ for $\rm\:n\ge 2,\:$ and $\,\rm f(2)>0,\,$ which is easy.

For many more examples see my [posts on telescopy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:242+telescopy)

Answer (score 0):

To prove the inductive step, expand so that we have $$k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 > 2k + 3$$

By hypothesis, $k^3 > 2k+1$. It thus suffices to show $3k^2 + 3k + 1 > 2$, or, equivalently, $3(k + \frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{7}{4} > 0$ which holds for $k\geq2$

Comment: I want to make sure I understand this. So 3k2+3k+1>2, so is it solved by saying 3k2+3k-1>0.

Comment: @xXNathan360Xx Well, they're equivalent statements. Adding or subtracting numbers from an inequality doesn't change anything.

Comment: So would I end this proof by saying: Since we know 3k^2+3k+1 > 2, we know that the original statement is true as well?

Comment: @xXNathan360Xx Basically. You're using the fact that $a>b, c>d \Longrightarrow a+c>b+d$.

Comment: So I can say: k^3+3k^2+3k+1>2k+3 since k^3 > 2k+3 and we know 3k^2+3k+1>2, due to a > b and c > d thus a + c > b + d.

Comment: @xXNathan360Xx Yup. But it should be $k^3 > 2k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it by induction.
You can also look at $n^3-2n-1$.

$n^3-2n-1=n^3-n-n-1=n(n-1)(n+1)-(n+1)=(n+1)(n^2-n-1)=(n+1)(n^2-2n+1+n-2)=(n+1)(n-1)^2+(n+1)(n-2)>0$

We know from the condition $n\ge2$ that $n+1$ has to be positive, $(n-1)^2$ is always positive and so is $n-2$. So it's clear why the whole term has to be positive for $n\ge2$.